# Can't make it work Ajax with MVC 3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

This is my Controller method

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RemoveValue()
    {

        return View();

    }
```

And this is how i am trying to access to method

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Asenkron process", "RemoveValue")
```

But if i remove HttpPost attribute then it works.

I have tested this on MVC 3 RC 2

Comment: Anyone has no idea ? works on you ?

Comment: I am also having this problem when I try to do the MvcMusicStore tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The `[HttpPost]` attribute means that that method can only be reached via a POST request. If you were to look at the request in Firebug or something similar, you would see the request being made, and get a `500` error in response.

If you want the link to perform a POST, change it to:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Asenkron process", "RemoveValue", new AjaxOptions {HttpMethod="POST"})
```

EDIT

Upon further reading of the docs, Ajax.ActionLink does nothing with the result it gets unless you specify something for it to do. It also does a POST by default it seems, so the AjaxOptions isn't needed. If you want to display the contents of whatever is in the RemoveValue view, you need to do something like the following:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Text","RemoveValue", new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId="resultDiv" })
<div id="resultDiv">
</div>
```

The contents of resultDiv will be whatever is returned from the Action.

If you are looking for just some sort of confirmation:

```
<script>
  function onSuccess()
  {
    alert("Success!");
  }

  function onFailure()
  {
    alert("Failed!");
  }
</script>
@Ajax.ActionLink("Text","RemoveValue", new AjaxOptions {OnSuccess="onSuccess", OnFailure="onFailure" })
```

This is, of course, assuming you want an asynchronous request. If you want a normal synchronous POST, where the browser goes to a new page, do something like this:

```
using(Html.BeginForm("ActionName","ControllerName",FormMethod.Post))
{
  <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
}
```

If you do this, the Action you POST to should end with `return RedirectToAction("AnotherAction");`. The browser will then make a GET request to AnotherAction. This prevents duplicate actions when the user clicks the back button and the "Data must be resubmitted to the page" popup in browsers.

Hopefully this is slightly more helpful.

Comment: I have also tried this but didn't work. Does it works on you? have you tested ?

Comment: Looking further at the docs, I think a more appropriate question is what are you expecting to happen? I'm going to update my answer with more details.

Comment: I am expecting that method will be invoked but it doesn't happen.

Comment: Still no luck. Ajax.ActionLink use Get method even if i change it's HttpMethod property. I will gone mad. But i am able to make ajax with pure javascript codes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a Ajax.BeginForm around it?

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions{ UpdateTargetId="resultDiv", HttpMethod="Get"})) {
}